# How do I get rules to select a random node?

Tags: rules

I'm working on my cron rule that will post to twitter every cron run. Thing is for this rule I need it to post a random node that either conforms to specific values in certain fields, or does something else if that value is false. I could use some help figuring this out.

Basically if The value of X=y I want the view to respond with one action, but if the value of X <> y then I want it to do another. And I need it to do this on random nodes of a sepcific content type.

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

See [How to Use EntityFieldQuery](https://www.drupal.org/node/1343708), particularly the section "Random ordering".